# Pagination on multiple searches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, pagination

I have the following bit of code:

```
def index
    @games = Game.gamsearch(params[:gamsearch])
    @games = Game.consearch(params[:consearch]) if params[:consearch].present?
    @games = Game.gensearch(params[:gensearch]) if params[:gensearch].present?
    @games = Game.where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%") if params[:game_name].present?
    @games = Game.where("console = ?", params[:console]) if params[:console].present?
end
```

What I wish to do is have all of these results paginate. Now I know how to paginate from a singular search as I have done here:

```
def index
   user_relation = case params[:username].present?
   when true then User.where("username LIKE ?", "#{params[:username]}%")
   else User
   end
   @users = user_relation.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order => 'created_at desc', :per_page => 10
end
```

But the games controller has 5 possible methods of search and was wondering how I would apply pagination to it.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by appending the search results all to the same array and than paginate this array.

like:

```
def index
    @games = Array.new()
    @games << Game.gamsearch(params[:gamsearch])
    @games << Game.consearch(params[:consearch]) if params[:consearch].present?
    @games << Game.gensearch(params[:gensearch]) if params[:gensearch].present?
    @games << Game.where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%") if params[:game_name].present?
    @games << Game.where("console = ?", params[:console]) if params[:console].present?
end
```

and then just paginate the `@games` object.

hope this helps!